# How 極めつけは is understood here?

Tags: meaning, slang

I am uncertain about the meaning of 極めつけは～ in the below panel:

[image]

The author explains that computer games developed in 90's can use up to 15 colours simultaneously on display.

After some Google search, it seems like 極めつけは is synonymous to 最高. But I don't think it makes sense in this context. Maybe it means something like "Interestingly, ..."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionary entries ([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%A5%B5%E3%82%81%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D/#jn-58708), [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%A5%B5%E3%82%81%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91)) seem to list various rare usages of 極めつけ, but practically speaking, this word almost always refers to the most striking/extreme part of a story. In English, 極めつけは would translate to "the best/worst part is, ...".